# How can extract a value from object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Suppose to have this arrat:

```
var categoria=[{"5":"Widgets"}]; // the array can change now it 5 but can be 7
```

I need to extact the value "Widget" so I do :

```
categoria[Object.keys(categoria)[0]])
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone can help me?

Comment: you could do categoria[0]['5'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the key you need to to do `Object.keys(categoria[0])` and to access the correct index within `categoria` you can use `categoria[0]` like this:

```js
var categoria=[{"5":"Widgets"}];
var result = categoria[0][Object.keys(categoria[0])];
console.log(result);
```

Same code with multiple different keys:

```js
var categoria = [{
  "5": "Widgets"
}, {
  "27": "Something Else"
}, {
  "9": "More"
}];

for (i = 0; i < categoria.length; i++) {
  var result = categoria[i][Object.keys(categoria[i])];
  console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your key is static, it should be like `categoria[0]['5']`.

Otherwise `categoria[0][Object.keys(categoria[0])[0]]` will work.